# Как изменить расположение блока по оси Z?

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 блока, `<header>` который идет на всю ширину окна и под ним идет другой блок, но у `header position: fixed`  и второй блок расположен под первый, а должен быть под ним. как решить этот вопрос?

```css
header {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: url("image/banner.jpg") no-repeat center top / cover;
  background-size: auto cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 974px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading clearfix">
      <img src="image/logo.png" alt=" logo" class="logo">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <label for="menu-checkbox" class="toogle-button" data-open="Меню" data-close="Закрыть" onclick></label>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Домой</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: смотрите `css` свойство `z-index`.

Comment: А второй блок ХХХХДЕ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то Ваш второй блок должен быть над фиксированным header. Для этого у второго блока надо задать **position:relative** и указать **z-index**.
Пример вот такой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            header {
                width:100%;
                height:200px;
                background:green;
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
            #secondBlock {
                width:80%;
                height:250px;
                background:red;
                position:relative;
                z-index:100;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <div id="secondBlock">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Будет вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, вернул. Не совсем понял, что там заминусили, но решил удалить, чтобы не путать людей.